# About writing C ++ RedHawk startup program

Tags: redhawksdr

We are using RedHawk v2.1 on xilinx Zynq7035 Platform. Based on the following URL, I built it with a project from which Python was deleted. 
https://github.com/Axios-Engineering/openembedded-hawk#features--options
Prior to using this project, Python described the startup program. But there is not Python on current Project. Could you tell us how to write the following Python functions for RedHawk in C ++?

```
dom = redhawk.attach('REDHAWK_DEV')
wave0 = dom.createApplication
dom.devices[0].connect
wave0.start()
dom.devices[0].start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should review example 3 in the omniORB documentation. It should provide you with an example of resolving a CORBA object from the naming service and making the IDL calls on it. Documentation [here](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni40/omniORB/omniORB002.html)

Comment: I'm sorry to understand..... For example, when you write Startup program on your project installed PC(or Proccesor). then do you write StartUp C++ program of CORBA and IDL ? How discribe connect  between device and waveform? How to Start  device and waveform?
Sorry for the lack of knowledge of RedHawk.

Comment: DomainManager and DeviceManager is startup as nodeBooter on own processor(ARM A9 in Zynq). After, Auto start waveform depend on Startup C++ program. I believe that C ++ startup programs can be composed of Service_impl classes and functions.Is my opinion correct?

Comment: Originally it seems that Python realizes a useful function for making Red Hawk easier to use.In order to start up in C ++, I think that it is necessary to convert functions written in Python to C ++.I would like to ask a new question.